# How to redirect to public site from Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I bought a domain via AWS Route 53. I want users to be redirected to a wordpress.com site. I tried creating a CNAME record to do this in the AWS Route 53 console, but I keep getting the error: "Bad request. (InvalidChangeBatch 400: RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name mydomain.com. is not permitted at apex in zone mydomain.com.)"
How can I get around this?

Comment: Redirect to `www.wordpress.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the guide here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/

For https, you maybe want to look into cloudfront (out of the box if you follow the steps above you will only get http) : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https.html

Last link (it shows everything e2e by walking through the console): https://dev.to/marklocklear/redirecting-a-domain-with-https-using-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-526h